# jasper decimal separator being ignored

Tags: jasper-reports, format, double

In a jasper report I use a JSON datasource.
This datasource contains numbers (e.g. 159.994).

There is a field of class `java.lang.double` (let's call it "doubleField") and a text field with this field and a pattern (`"#,##0.00 ¤ (brutto)"`).
The pattern works fine (german currency format) but if I print out just the value of the doubleField the expected output would be "195,99" or "159.994".
But in fact it is `"159.994,00"` or `"159994.0"`.

There was a solution changing the language of the report from "groovy" to "JavaScript" but this won't help and is also not applicable.

There is a "quick&dirty" solution (without being quick) to just take the JSON value as a String and then cast it to a double in the text field. This works fine but it's dirty and not really quick.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is. You say the pattern works fine, so that's not the problem. Then you say 'But in fact it is "159.994,00" or "159994.0'.  So which is it, 159.994,00 or 159994.0?  Is it printing both?  And why is that a problem when the formatted output is correct?

Comment: problem is: The pattern only works if the field is a string and I cast it to a double by myself in the text field.
IMHO it would be cleaner to just declare the field as a "double" and not as a "string" and cast it later...

Comment: Ok, that clearly states the problem.  I'm posting my next comment as an answer because I can't get all the text and formatting I need in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Jasper report definition.  I'm just including a few things from that report definition that I think might be relevant to your problem.

First, I have several field definitions.  Here are two of them:

```
<field name="FundFixedBeginningBalance" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription>
        <![CDATA[FundFixedBeginningBalance/FundFixedBeginningBalanceValue]]>
    </fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="FundNonFixedBeginningBalance" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription>
        <![CDATA[FundNonFixedBeginningBalance/FundNonFixedBeginningBalanceValue]]>
    </fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Note how both are defined with `class="java.lang.Double"`.  I'm using XPath expressions because my data is in XML, but that is not fundamentally different from JSON.  Later, in the report layout section I have:

```
    <textField pattern="#,##0.00 ;(#,##0.00)" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="368" y="52" width="100" height="14" uuid="deac984d-39b8-49f4-b4d2-28e66681c098">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
        </reportElement>
        <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FundFixedBeginningBalance} + $F{FundNonFixedBeginningBalance}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

Notice there is no casting within the `textFieldExpression` element; just substituting both fields in with `$F` and adding them together (and this prints correctly).  Are you doing something different?

Comment: I don't even calculate. Instead I just write something like:
 `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FundFixedBeginningBalance}]]></textFieldExpression>`

Comment: What does your JSON look like?  Here's what my XML looks like:      `<FundFixedBeginningBalanceValue>46401.54</FundFixedBeginningBalanceValue>`.  Note that there are no characters separating thousands and there is a period separating cents.  Is it possible you have European formatting for JSON (e.g. 46.401,54 or 46401,54) and American while Jasper things you are using American formatting?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "...and Jasper thinks you are using American formatting?"

Comment: I noticed that you said that the JSON contains numbers like this: `159.994`.  This is different that the numbers contains in my XML.  Using a text editor that supports regular expressions, can you alter your JSON so that it looks like "American" JSON (numbers formatted like `159994` or `159994.00`) and see how Jasper handles that.  Perhaps the problem is related to how the JSON is constrcted.

Comment: We use `"value": 1872.37`. This is not an european format instead it is "standard" JSON. Unfortunately some values have more decimals like `"value2": 1969.7199999999998`. Without the decimals, everything works fine: `"value3": 42`.
I don't know what we could change in the JSON as I tried to change the locale in Jasper without any effect.